# Performing gap analysis with line and polygon layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

How do I perform gap analysis with line and polygon layer in QGIS?

I have 2 vector layers. The first vector layer has line features and second layer has polygon features as in the following images.

[image: Figure 1: Vector Layer with Line features]

[image: Figure 2: Vector Layer with Polygon features]

[image: Overlapping Lines and Polygon features]

I am trying to perform a gap analysis that is cutting the lines at segments the polygons do not overlay the lines in QGIS.

Shapefiles of line and polygon layers are accessible from the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11GhQODoPby9SCnp9WcydOBJHVS3O1Lsv?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean exactly with a Gap Analysis, you probably do not mean this [Gap Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_analysis), do not you? For me your "Gap Analysis" sound more like a ["Difference"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference), where using of the ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) is also feasible.

Answer (score 2):

As your polygon layer has invalid geometries, you have to run first this method of Processing tool (Fix geometries). Both layers (I named Polygons as Polygons_fixed) loaded in QGIS look as follow.

[image]

Afterward, you need to run Difference Processing tool with following parameters:

[image]

After click in Run, resulting layer looks as follow. I used an opacity of 20 % in Polygons_fixed for corroborating that produced line layer effectively corresponds to lines which do not overlap.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simpel example cutting the lines not intersecting a polygon using QGIS Virtual Layers.

```
select p.id, st_intersection(l.geometry, p.geometry) as geometry 
from test_line l
inner join test_poly p on st_intersects(l.geometry, p.geometry)
```

Input a linestring and three polygons.

[image]

New virtual layer with linestring intersecting polygons.

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants the contrary: the part of the lines that do **not** overlap the polygons.

Comment: Yes. I am looking into the method to find lines which do not overlap.